# Handling static links from Wordpress API page content in React Router

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, react-router

I'm building a react app with React Router using wordpress as a headless cms, and I've come across a problem where I can't handle the links within the page content. I edited the link from `yourwebsite.com/about/` to `/about` within Wordpress, and the routing works on the frontend, but it refreshes the page at the same time. Is there a way of telling router to see these static content links as routes?

Comment: Are you using `<Link>` or `<a>`?

Comment: <a> within Wordpress.

Comment: I can only think of either parsing the HTML from Wordpress and rendering it with React (e.g. [`react-html-parsre`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser)) to replace your route `<a>` with `<Link>`, or make a `useEffect` which hooks directly into all `<a>` DOM nodes which are your frontend routes to add a `click` event handler that calls `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the browser navigation, then `history.push()`es link manually.

Comment: Great idea! I’ll take a look at this later and get back to you

Comment: This one worked a dream - I used the html parser package and that worked seemlessly

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `react-html-parser` as suggested by cbr in the comments. The documentation for implementing the transform function was minimal, so below is how I completed it:

```
export default function ContentBlock({
  children, className, tagName
}) {
  const Tag = tagName;
  const domain = 'www.yourdomain.co.uk';

  function transform(node) {
    // convert <a> to React-Router <Link>
    if (node.type === 'tag' && node.name === 'a') {
      // Only apply the transform to internal links
      if(node.attribs.href.indexOf(domain) > 0) {
        const href = node.attribs.href.split(domain)[1].split('/')[1];
        const classes = node.attribs.class ? node.attribs.class : '';
        const label = node.children[0].data;

        return <Link to={`/${href}`} className={classes}>{label}</Link>
      } 
    }
  }

  return (
    <Tag className={className} >
      { ReactHtmlParser(children, {transform}) }
    </Tag>
  )
}
```